# Checking for a particular string format in Oracle 11g

Tags: regex, plsql, oracle11g

In Oracle 11g, I need to check perform a check to see if the following format is true (i.e. via a regular expression):

```
PaaaaE0%
PaaaaD2%
```

where this value is of the following format:

```
P ( followed by any 4 alphanumeric digits) E or D (followed by atleast 1 numeric digit)
```

As part of the 4 alphanumeric digits, if alpha then they need to be uppercase.

For now, I have tried something like:

```
REGEXP_LIKE('PWOOOE12s3','[P][:alnum:]{4}[ED][:digit:]{1}')
```

Comment: Pls see updated question but unsure if correct and unsure how to ensure uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close:

- Matching a charter class should be written as `[[:digit:]]`. Note the outer braces for a matching list.
- `{n}` matches exactly `n` occurences, use `+` to match one or more occurences.
- `[:upper:]` matches uppercase letters, matching list `[[:upper:]|[:digit:]]` matches any uppercase letter or digit.
- I also added `^` anchor to match only from the beginning of the string. You can left it out if it doesn't fit your purpose.

This should get the job done:

```
SQL@xe> !cat so40.sql
with
data_ as (
  select 1 id, 'PWOOOE12s3' str from dual union
  select 2 id, 'PwoooE12s3' str from dual
)
select id, str from data_
where regexp_like(str, '^P[[:upper:]|[:digit:]]{4}[ED][[:digit:]]+')
;
SQL@xe> @so40

        ID STR
---------- ----------
         1 PWOOOE12s3

SQL@xe>
```